# android multiplayer, database connectivity api

Tags: php, android, multiplayer

am thinking to make a android multiplier game. Am looking for API which can connect to my database and access data continuously. In my mind i have a idea about this. I know how to connect to database with php and access data. But the problem is i cant figure out how to access data continuously until game runs. If you have a new idea please share it with me. Or else suggest me some API's or some methods or some links which may be useful. Any help will be appreciated.